# How to use HTML content in Android listview....?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, htmlspecialchars

I am developing an app where i need to use some maths special characters in it. After a long search in google i found the following solution i.e.., [How to put some special math symbols in TextView, EditView or other Android UI element.](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/12/how-to-put-some-special-math-symbols-in-textview-editview-or-other-android-ui-element) As per the above link if i am using textview means it is working good. But how to use the following **"HTML.frommHtml()"** in listview. I tried but it is getting error......

code: (using Textview)

```
//by using textview

  String htmlStringWithMathSymbols = " &#8706;   &#8710;   &#8719;   &#8721;      &#61;   &#8800;   &#8776;   &#8801;";
  txtv.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlStringWithMathSymbols));
```

How to use the following **"HTML.frommHtml()"** with listview. when i am adding same code for listview it is getting error...

code: (using ListView)

```
//by using listview

 String[] andi={"andi 4","andi 5" , "&#8706;" , "&#8710;","&#8719;"};    

ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, andi);
    lv.setAdapter(Html.fromHtml(adp));
```

While using with listview in the place of "fromHtml()" it is showing error as **"The method fromHtml(String) in the type Html is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayAdapter)"**.

**So how can i use the following "Html.fromHtml()" code with listview or spinner....**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
CharSequence[] andi={Html.fromHtml("andi 4"), Html.fromHtml("andi 5") , Html.fromHtml("&#8706;") , Html.fromHtml("&#8710;"),Html.fromHtml("&#8719;")};    

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adp = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, andi);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
```

in your code you try to set string value for adapter and passing the adapter to `fromHtml` function

Comment: That's a great code but in place of "String[]"  need to take "CharSequence[]" because as per the the following code, array declared are not recognizing as array of strings because of "not using double quotes". It worked by using CharSequence[]....  Thanks for your code...

Comment: yes... you are right. just updated the answer :). thanks for pointing the mistake.